# Android Notification Click - don't backstack activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I have a service in background which gives a notification.

I want the next thing:

If I click the notification and the app is not opened open the XActivity.

If the app is opened and the XActivity is created, go there and don't recreate the activity (because if this happen, on back key i will see the same activity again).

My notification code

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("New posts!")
                    .setContentText("New funny posts had just arrived! Click here to see them!");
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, XActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    int mNotificationId = 001;
```

// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

I start the service from the XActivity. (just a activity name example)

Thank you.

Comment: Your problem is when you click on notification XActivity open and when you press device back button XActivity is till there, you want to come out of the app. pls let me clear.

Comment: See [Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse) here and find 'Setting up a special activity PendingIntent'.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem, what i did was , i added this line `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to my activity in manifest, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Problem for duplicate activity in your case is because of standard structure design of Activity in Android. For creating only single instance of activity (no duplication) you need to give [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) property to your activity in your manifest file. You can use **singleTop** property for this behaviour. You can read more in provided link.

In Addition, for new data access you can use [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) for new intent coming to this activity and set intent using [setIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setIntent(android.content.Intent)) and continue working with new data.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.